# Get vars of prev and next post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to make a script which will work in single.php template on footer post. I want to have info about previous custom_post_type and next custom_post_type.

I've written this:

```
<?php
  // get info about prev_post
  $prev_post = get_previous_post();
  $k_id = $prev_post->post_author;

  $p_link = get_page_link($prev_post->ID);
  $p_title = $prev_post->post_title;
  $p_date = mysql2date('d F Y', $prev_post->post_date, false);
  $p_author = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $k_id );
?>

<a class="p_title" href="<?php echo $p_link; ?>"><?php echo $p_title; ?></a>
<p class="p_post"><?php echo $p_date; ?> - <?php echo $p_author; ?></p>
```

Everything works well, but permalink is broken. The custom_post_type url is:

```
http://mypage.com/customposttype/title_of_entry
```

but link leads to:

```
http://mypage.com/title_of_entry
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: Any difference if you use `get_permalink( $prev_post->ID )` instead of `get_page_link()` ?

Comment: `get_permalink( $prev_post->ID )` works. Thanks